# Adding attribute to XML using JACKSON from JSON input

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

This is my JSON

```
    {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3",
      "field4": "value4",
      "field5": "value5"
    }
```

This is XML which I want to convert to:

```
<root>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    <element2>value2</element2>
    <element3 element4="value4" element5="value5">value3</element3>
</root>
```

**So basically, I want to make element 4 & 5 as attributes to element3. Hope I am making sense so far.**

This is what my pojo to parse JSON looks like

```
public class JSONMessage {

    Date timestamp;

    @JsonProperty("field1")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element1")
    String element1;

    @JsonProperty("field2")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element2")
    String element2;

    @JsonProperty("field3")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element3")
    String element3;

    @JsonProperty("field4")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element4")
    String element4;

    @JsonProperty("field5")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element5")
    String element5;
}
```

This is what my pojo to parse JSON to XML looks like

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "linkFoundEvent")
public class XMLMessage {
    private Date element1;
    private String element1;
    private String element2;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element3")
    private Element3 element3;

}
```

And for Element3, I've written this class -

```
public class Element3{
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String element3;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element4", isAttribute = true)
    private String element4;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element5", isAttribute = true)
    private String element5;
}
```

How can I make Element4 and Element5 as attributes to Element4? Please help! Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two POJO classes (one for JSON & one for XML) to achieve the transformation from input json to output xml (if that's all you want here), check below full working code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText;

public class JsonXmlTransformation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        System.out.println(jsonToXml());
    }

    /**
     * json to xml transformation 
     */
    public static String jsonToXml() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        String json = "{\r\n      \"field1\": \"value1\",\r\n      \"field2\": \"value2\",\r\n      \"field3\": \"value3\",\r\n      \"field4\": \"value4\",\r\n      \"field5\": \"value5\"\r\n    }";
        return new XmlMapper().writeValueAsString(new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Message.class));
    }
}

class Message {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element1")
    String element1;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element2")
    String element2;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element3")
    Elements elements;

    @JsonCreator
    public Message(@JsonProperty("field1") String element1, @JsonProperty("field2") String element2,
            @JsonProperty("field3") String element3, @JsonProperty("field4") String element4, @JsonProperty("field5") String element5) {
        super();
        this.element1 = element1;
        this.element2 = element2;
        this.elements = new Elements(element3, element4, element5); 
    }
}

class Elements{

    public Elements(String element3, String element4, String element5) {
        super();
        this.element3 = element3;
        this.element4 = element4;
        this.element5 = element5;
    }

    @JacksonXmlText
    String element3;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element4", isAttribute = true)
    String element4;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element5", isAttribute = true)
    String element5;
}
```

Input:

```
{
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "field3": "value3",
      "field4": "value4",
      "field5": "value5"
    }
```

Output:

```
<Message>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    <element2>value2</element2>
    <element3 element4="value4" element5="value5">value3</element3>
</Message>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working, the output I am now getting is
<element1/><element2/><element3/> and so on..

You said I don't need two class, but you're using two classes, Message & Elements. If I strictly follow the beginning and end of your classes, I can't see that one is a subclass. 

This line where you're transforming method in the class is little confusing and is giving me JsonParseException. Can you please simplify that? Thanks again for helping here.

Comment: I added the standalone executable code, and amended the answer to make it more simplified. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Thank you, Amith. I had to change few things around but it's working now. :)